# Prevent mixing of weights in a bone

Tags: bones, weight-painting

[image]
Both bones enabled

I'm trying to add a bone to deform the character, so I could easily make it look fat or skinny. The problem is that the other bones seem to be affecting the result, even thought they are not moved (their weight maps cause the unwanted deformation). You can notice the deformation in the right side of the first picture. Can you explain me why is this and how can I prevent this?

This character is for a video game.

Comment: upload your file? http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Removed a picture, the link limit

Comment: I think you should use shape keys https://youtu.be/gDZcmAWL2jA?t=21s and use a  driver to drive the shape key influence, on the scale of the bone. So if you scale up the bone, the shape key gets activated and the character gets fatter.

Comment: Shape keys don't work in most game engines. I can't use shape keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete what vertex group each individual vertex belongs to

3D view Editor-->Edit mode-->(n) properties shelf-->vertex weights.

[image]

Imagine each vertex group = a muscle.

The more vertex groups control a single vertex= the more muscles are connected to that vertex .

So when you are trying to make the belly bigger with one muscle, the other muscles are still attached=you get uneven stretching.

And the muscle strength can only be changed manually in weight paint mode or by using the vertex weight modifier.

Comment: But the thing is, I need to bend the character from a deformed place.

Comment: will the vertex weight modifier work for game engines? How about drivers, do those work in game engines? Is this in Blender Game Render?

Comment: jme3, which is a rather primitive engine. Yes, weights work in games but they are not "modifiers". It is pretty much the only complex system supported natively by all. You pointed me to the right direction and I learned something. What we'll do is that we use an armature modifier to fatten the model, then the result will be posed. This is also easy to implement with code in jme. If you think that this is a bad idea, please tell me.

Comment: I dont have any experience working on games. I started learning blender this year by reading the Blender reference manual. Most of what I read about was on "animating" for videos.